# Can't move vertices in Edit or Sculpt Mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, transforms, sculpt-mode

When I am in Edit (or Sculpt Mode) and try to transform a selection (g,r or s) nothing happens.  However, I can seen in the header that values are changing. None of my channels are locked.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot or even share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: it's too large to upload.  here is a link for the blend file.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fMmUN0wGz18ic2jOqiEt-3SSg332gCJt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: btw, if you download the file, it's the main body of the character that has the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the shapekey's *Shape Key Edit Mode* option (don't know how it works though):

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  You answered that fast.  King!

Comment: In Sculpt mode you need to put the Value at 1, if it still doesn't work please share your file again